# Doctrine wants to alter every identity field

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I've just run composer update - to get the latest version of Symfony 2.2.1 (and associated bundles) and now when i run `doctrine:schema:update` it wants to update all tables :

```
ALTER TABLE core_billing_account ALTER COLUMN id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE core_billing_account_priority ALTER COLUMN id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE core_billing_account_status ALTER COLUMN id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE core_connection ALTER COLUMN id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE core_connection_custom_field ALTER COLUMN id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE core_connection_services ALTER COLUMN id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE core_country ALTER COLUMN id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE core_currency ALTER COLUMN id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE core_customer_hierarchy ALTER COLUMN id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE core_customer_tariff ALTER COLUMN id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE core_extra_cost_type ALTER COLUMN id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE core_mno ALTER COLUMN id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE core_mno_services ALTER COLUMN id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE core_mno_status ALTER COLUMN id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE core_sim ALTER COLUMN id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE core_size_uom ALTER COLUMN id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE core_tax_rate ALTER COLUMN id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE core_time_uom ALTER COLUMN id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE core_usage ALTER COLUMN id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL
```

this fails as MSSQL doesn't like the syntax - but i don't understand why - i've only added a new entity (`core_usage`) but it wants to update every table. I have tried clearing cache but no difference ... HELP !!!

### Update

Also happens when dropping and re-creating the database ... [Issue reported on the DoctrineBundle repo](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/issues/184)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is fixed in a later version of Doctrine than I was using ... upgraded to doctrine 2.3.4 and its resolved.

[Details here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DBAL-482)